# Click event only works on the second click

Tags: javascript, html, css

i hope you guys fine, well..

I'm doing a To Do List, and there is a problem in my code, which I've been trying to solve for a few days, and no effective results was made..

> If you guys test in the snippet with me, i am sure, that will be more
> clear to understand.

When i click in some list element, my javascript should change or add the className, and add a class call **'selected'**.

because, when i will click in the remove button, they will delete all elements with 'selected' classList in the list. (as you can see in the code)

But the className a not being add to the tag 



 in the *first click*, just works if i *click* in the

element *one more time*.

i simplified my code, just to show the real problem:

Link to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/myqrzcs2/

```js
const textoTarefa = document.getElementById('texto-tarefa');
const criarTarefa = document.getElementById('criar-tarefa');
const listaTarefas = document.getElementById('lista-tarefas');
criarTarefa.onclick = function click() {
  const lista = document.createElement('li');
  lista.className = 'lista';
  lista.id = 'lista';
  lista.tabIndex = '0';
  lista.innerHTML = textoTarefa.value;
  listaTarefas.appendChild(lista);
  document.body.appendChild(listaTarefas);
  textoTarefa.value = '';
};
const completedLine = document.querySelector('ol');

function umClick(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    const listas = document.querySelectorAll('.lista');
    listas.forEach((i) => {
      i.addEventListener('click', function semNomeDois() {
        listas.forEach((j) => j.classList.remove('selected'));
        this.classList.add('selected');
      });
    });
  }
}
completedLine.addEventListener('click', umClick);

function removeSelected() {
  // teste
  const listaSelected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
  for (let i = 0; i < listaSelected.length; i += 1) {
    listaSelected[i].remove();
  }
}
```

```css
.lista:focus {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My List</h1>
  </header>
  <input id='texto-tarefa' type="text" />
  <button id='criar-tarefa' type="submit" onClick='click()'>Add</button>
  <ol id='lista-tarefas'>
  </ol>
  <button id='remover-selecionado' type="submit" onClick='removeSelected()'>Remove Selected (Only One)</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> But how can i make the class be add, just in the first click, not in the second?

---

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for that, you are right.. well the thing is that  when i click in the element <li> to add the class 'selected', doesnt work, just in the second time that i click, the class it is add.. And i dont know why..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please clearify your question in order to make it understandable and answerable. Also, could you please try running your code on multiple browsers? And confirm if the problem a browser specific or a general problem.

Comment: okay, i will try to clearify more right now, thanks for the feedback, and will try in diferent browsers, just need some minutes to fix and test. But if try to use my list, to add and delete it, they will understand, maybe it is something that will be more clear if we do it.

Comment: i test and the problem continues, i will edit now.

Comment: I've added an answer. However, the problem isn't visible to me to be honest.

Comment: @VanessaSantos I figured your problem, I will add an edit to the answer in seconds. Btw, the answer still works but I will explain why.

Comment: okay, take you time, i will be here. and thank you.

Comment: you can't do that : `lista.id = 'lista';` because All `id` must be UNIQUE  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you call the function `umClick` and call the function to add `.selected` within a `click event` in the same function `umClick`.

What happens is the click event `completedLine.addEventListener('click', umClick);` happens before the `i.addEventListener('click', function semNomeDois()` event. This is why you need a first click on the `ol` tag for only the first time.

To fixes this you have multiple options:

1. instead of calling `click` event on `ol` tag you can call `mousedown` which happens before `click` event.
2. Calling a click event on the `li` elements on creation, which needs a new function.
3. Depending on Vektor's answer, you can remove the unnecessary `click` event inside the first `click` event.

Also, I've made the red highlight on the `.selected` class instead of `:focus`, just to make it clear when the item is selected.

```
.selected {
   background: red;
}
```

### First Solution

```js
const textoTarefa = document.getElementById('texto-tarefa');
const criarTarefa = document.getElementById('criar-tarefa');
const listaTarefas = document.getElementById('lista-tarefas');
criarTarefa.onclick = function click() {
  const lista = document.createElement('li');
  lista.className = 'lista';
  lista.id = 'lista';
  lista.tabIndex = '0';
  lista.innerHTML = textoTarefa.value;
  listaTarefas.appendChild(lista);
  document.body.appendChild(listaTarefas);
  textoTarefa.value = '';
};
const completedLine = document.querySelector('ol');

function umClick(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    const listas = document.querySelectorAll('.lista');
    listas.forEach((i) => {
      i.addEventListener('click', function semNomeDois() {
        listas.forEach((j) =>{
          if(j != event.target)
            j.classList.remove('selected');
        });
        this.classList.add('selected');
      });
    });
  }
}
completedLine.addEventListener('mousedown', umClick);

function removeSelected() {
  // teste
  const listaSelected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
  for (let i = 0; i < listaSelected.length; i += 1) {
    listaSelected[i].remove();
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My List</h1>
  </header>
  <input id='texto-tarefa' type="text" />
  <button id='criar-tarefa' type="submit" onClick='click()'>Add</button>
  <ol id='lista-tarefas'>
  </ol>
  <button id='remover-selecionado' type="submit" onClick='removeSelected()'>Remove Selected (Only One)</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Second Solution

```js
const textoTarefa = document.getElementById('texto-tarefa');
const criarTarefa = document.getElementById('criar-tarefa');
const listaTarefas = document.getElementById('lista-tarefas');
criarTarefa.onclick = function click() {
  const lista = document.createElement('li');
  lista.className = 'lista';
  lista.id = 'lista';
  lista.tabIndex = '0';
  lista.innerHTML = textoTarefa.value;
  listaTarefas.appendChild(lista);
  lista.addEventListener('click',function(){
    itemClick(this);
  });
  document.body.appendChild(listaTarefas);
  textoTarefa.value = '';
};

function itemClick(item) {
    const listas = document.querySelectorAll('.lista');
    listas.forEach((j) =>j.classList.remove('selected'));
   item.classList.add('selected');
}

function removeSelected() {
  // teste
  const listaSelected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
  for (let i = 0; i < listaSelected.length; i += 1) {
    listaSelected[i].remove();
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>My List</h1>
  </header>
  <input id='texto-tarefa' type="text" />
  <button id='criar-tarefa' type="submit" onClick='click()'>Add</button>
  <ol id='lista-tarefas'>
  </ol>
  <button id='remover-selecionado' type="submit" onClick='removeSelected()'>Remove Selected (Only One)</button>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, oh my God, it works. I will take some moment to study you code, to dont make this mistakes again, thank you so much.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it clear what fixed the problem.

Comment: so much code for so little to do ...

Comment: @MisterJojo Isn't StackOverflow made for explainig code? I'm just trying to explain in details :)

Comment: that's good, but SO it's also for code review

Answer (score 2):

I think you got off on the wrong foot in programming this.
Here is the way I use, may it inspire you.

```js
const
  textoTarefa  = document.getElementById('texto-tarefa')
, criarTarefa  = document.getElementById('criar-tarefa')
, removerSelec = document.getElementById('remover-selecionado')
, listaTarefas = document.getElementById('lista-tarefas')
  ;
var li_selected = null
  ;
textoTarefa.oninput = () =>
  {
  criarTarefa.disabled = (textoTarefa.value.trim().length ===0 )
  }
criarTarefa.onclick = () =>
  {
  listaTarefas.appendChild( document.createElement('li')).textContent =  textoTarefa.value.trim()
  textoTarefa.value = ''
  textoTarefa.focus()
  criarTarefa.disabled = true
  }
listaTarefas.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('li')) return
  if (!!li_selected && li_selected !== target ) li_selected.classList.remove('listaSelect')
  li_selected = target.classList.toggle('listaSelect') ? target : null
  removerSelec.disabled = !li_selected
  }
removerSelec.onclick = () =>
  {
  listaTarefas.removeChild(li_selected)
  li_selected = null
  removerSelec.disabled = true
  }
```

```css
.listaSelect {
  background: #ff0000c4;
  }
ol#lista-tarefas {
  cursor : pointer
  }
```

```html
<input  id='texto-tarefa' type="text" value="">
<button id='criar-tarefa' disabled>Add</button>
<button id='remover-selecionado' disabled>Remove Selected</button>
<ol id='lista-tarefas'></ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were unnecessarily adding an event listener to each item in the list.

You can check the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/msa9v2nf/

Since you're already checking which target element is clicked, there isn't any need to add an individual listener to each child item in the list.

I updated the `umClick` function:

```js
function umClick(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    const listas = document.querySelectorAll('.lista');
    
    listas.forEach((i) => {
      listas.forEach((j) => j.classList.remove('selected'));
      event.target.classList.add('selected');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understand your problem but,
If you want to add the style when selecting a item, just add the style to

```
.selected
```

If you want in focus, and remove the class when there is no focus, you may add an eventlistener to control that.

Comment: What happen, it is that when i click in the element <li> to add the class 'selected', doesnt work at first, just in the second time that i click, the class it is add.. And i dont know why..